# webpack encore compiles scss but does not output it

Tags: reactjs, symfony, webpack

I am trying to get scss compiling to work i my project. Using this as starting point: https://github.com/Limenius/symfony-react-sandbox which uses webpack-encore to create webpack config files.

If I understand it right I would just need to add     .enableSassLoader()
 to the config to make scss work. In the console when running webpack in dev mode, it seems to compile the scss files but I cannot see the output in the compiled html-code. No errors in console either. I am not sure if I understand it right but I am referencing my scss files inside each react container component like:

```
import styles from './app.scss';
```

I guess that this should work?

I hanve no ide on how to debug this...

Comment: webpack on dev mode does not spit files, they are in-memory. try looking at `localhost/thenameofyourcssfileonyourwebpackbuild.css`

Comment: I can not see the class-parameters in the html (in chrome) that I defined using className={styles.wrapper} either. So I guess that the problem lies before trying to require the compiled css-file.

Comment: paste your webpack config and html file